# Stop rotating images from pausing when hovering over them

Tags: javascript

I have rotating images which use javascript. The problem I am having is it pauses when the cursor is hovered over the top of the images.

How can I stop this from happening?

Original code from: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({
wrapperid: "fadeshow1", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
dimensions: [900, 600], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
imagearray: [
    ["01.jpg"],
    ["02.jpg"],
    ["03.jpg"],
    ["04.jpg"],
    ["05.jpg"],
    ["06.jpg"],
    ["07.jpg"],
    ["08.jpg"],
    ["09.jpg"],
    ["10.jpg"],
    ["11.jpg"] 
],
displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:7500, cycles:0, wraparound:false},
persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
fadeduration: 400, //transition duration (milliseconds)
descreveal: "none",
togglerid: ""
})
</script>
```

and...

```
 <div id="fadeshow1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in the fadeslideshow.js code itself ( http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeslideshow.js ), the if block from line 129 to 132 can simply be commented out.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
setting.$wrapperdiv.bind('mouseenter', function(){setting.ismouseover=true}) //pause slideshow mouseover
```

from `adeslideshow.js`

It will solve your problem